# Is a virtual machine efficient for isolating viruses from pop-up ads?

Tags: virus, virtualization

To be more clear, I would like to access movie streaming websites which have lots of (pop-up) ads and I’m fearful that I might deal with viruses.

Would VirtualBox help me isolate this type of viruses? What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: unless those viruses have a browser zero day that can evade browser sandbox and  execute code in your system coupled with zero day to break through the sandbox of a virtual machine.

Comment: No one in their right mind wont be burning those unless you are very high profile target

Comment: And use an adblocker